# Extjs 5.0.0 bar chart series label issue

Tags: extjs, charts

I am not able to display bar chart series label horizontally outside the bars.
Used display:'outside' and orientation:'horizontal' for bar chart label configuration, still no results.

Is it a bug in 5.0.0 or is there any other way to display label horizontally ?

Comment: Can you share some code, may you have missed something, or can you create a fiddle.

Comment: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1kfj|view/editor

change fiddle extjs version to 5.0.0.970 - it does'nt show up any results..
i m using 5.0.0 version in my application same code structure is created   but series label orientation is not taking any effect. its vertical.

Comment: Yes, Checking  the fiddle

Comment: hi UDID ,any update on this..stuck in between.. thanks

Comment: I will try this on weekend.

Comment: You want your code to run on 5.1 right ?

Comment: no, i want to run it on 5.0.0

Comment: still didnt find any solution for this.. :(